# Laptop keyboard becomes inresponsive (mostly when watching videos in YouTube)

Tags: drivers, keyboard, laptop, lenovo, youtube

For first time it happened a while ago when I was watching a YouTube video. At one moment the video hang for a moment and the very next moment the laptop keyboard just became inresponsive. I tried to type in text and nothing happened. I thought it was just an issue in browser, so I decided to type something in my dash search for quick check and it didn't work. Even more - the touchpad also didn't respond. None of commands worked. Only turn off button showed up all those options(turn off, restart, sleep mode etc.) when I pressed it. My USB mouse worked well though. I decided to restart to see what happens and a Novo Button Menu appearaded after restart. I got scared due to it's Windows-like look so I just held the turn off button to unpower my laptop. After turning back on all worked fine. However, a few hours later, when watching another YouTube video, this issue repeated. I decided to turn off computer rather than restart to see if it auto-fixes, but it just wouldn't turn off. So, again - I unpowered it. Well and it repeated more and more and not only YouTube. Several other browser sites ended up in the same. And in other sites I actually noticed that during the keyboard "turn-off", the laptop becomes completely inresponsive for like 3 seconds. And than it goes back normal, but keyboard doesn't respond any more. And this issue is really worrying me. Why? I'll tell it down below.

Some information:
Laptop: Lenovo IdeaPad Y700
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-6300HQ (with microcode drivers)
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX960M (with propiretary drivers)
RAM: 4 GB
OS: Linux Ubuntu 16.10 64-bit

Important notes:
This has only happened to me since 16.10 update. During the update I had a fatal crash, but technically I fixed it's consequences. After finding this bug I thought that the crash may be the reason so I did a complete reinstall of my OS(completely deleted all hard drive content and installed a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.10). After the reinstall this issue is still there. What really concerns me is that this issue could be a problem in my laptop. That is a case that I really wouldn't like to experience, unless I can fix it without spending money for that. The other case which I think it could possibly be(and I hope it is) is a driver bug in Ubuntu 16.10 that could be fixed later(as in some cases a crash report came a bit later and I surely sent it).

Any ideas, suggestions and help will be a good start for solving this.

Comment: So you  had 16.04 before and did not experience the issue? Could you try and boot a live system from the 16.04 (or whatever your last working version was) installation DVD/USB drive and try to reproduce the problem there? You should also try to reproduce it with a 16.10 live system instead of your disk installation to make sure nothing got messed up during the installation. Please report back whether and on which live system versions the problem still occurs. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/ideapad-y700-windows-10-keyboard-stops-working/td-p/3464406

Try updating your BIOS, but be careful - BIOS updates can brick your computer if not done properly. If you still have your windows partition, then boot into it and go to http://support.lenovo.com/ and see if you can update BIOS from there. If you don't have a windows partition, google how to make a bootable USB stick with a BIOS update for your computer. Before updating BIOS remember to backup all important data (just in case).

Comment: Just a note - I've never had a Windows partition on this computer(it came with FreeDOS which I completely replaced with Ubuntu). Also, what is that BIOS update you're talking about? What will it change? I took a look at the link and the issue seems to be a bit different from mine. What is more, it's on Windows and there can be huge differences between Linux and Windows in this case.